# How to read a sitemap and its directories?

Tags: xml, web-crawler, sitemap, robots.txt

I am building a web-crawler for this particular site

> http://www.dictionary.com

And after checking `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /site=
Disallow: /5480.iac.
Disallow: /go/
Disallow: /audio.html/
Disallow: /houseads/
Disallow: /askhome/
Disallow: /cite.html
Disallow: /23219321/iac.

Allow: /
Sitemap: http://www.dictionary.com/dictionary-sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

and from the site-map link I was able to download and read it. So my question is how do I read the site-map and find the directories it has disallowed me.

Sorry if my question is too vague but I couldn't understand how this works and I'm new to this subject.

Comment: The purpose of the sitemap is to help search engines to index the website. It should not contain any URLs that are disallowed in the robots.txt file.

Comment: @DanNagle So I am allowed to 'web-crawl' the site with my own web-crawler?

Answer (score 0):

You may not crawl URLs whose path starts with `/site=`, `/5480.iac.`, …, `/cite.html`, or `/23219321/iac.`.

For example,

you are **not allowed** to crawl URLs like these:

```
http://www.dictionary.com/go/
http://www.dictionary.com/go/foo
http://www.dictionary.com/go/foo/bar
```

you are **allowed** to crawl URLs like these:

```
http://www.dictionary.com/go
http://www.dictionary.com/go.html
http://www.dictionary.com/foo/go/
```

If the sitemap contains URLs you are not allowed to crawl according to the robots.txt, it’s still not allowed for you to crawl them.
While it might seem counterintuitive to include URLs that should not be crawled in the sitemap, it can make sense (e.g., because the sitemap gets used by other agents than crawlers, or because only a few specific bots are not allowed to crawl).